# how to avoid duplicate code when updating user information

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

i'm writing a controller in node js to update user information, on the front end i show the user the full form of his information and he can edit whatever fields he wants and then submits the request..now on the backend i need to check if the user has edited his password to hash it and then find the user by id and update his info, if he didn't change his password then i'll update the information without doing any hashing..but this is leaving some duplicate code..how can i avoid this?

```
router.put("/editprofile", upload.single('image'), fileSizeLimitErrorHandler, verifyUser, (req, res) => {
    let userInfo = req.body;
    const url = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host');
    if (req.file) {
        userInfo.image = url + '/uploads/profile_images/' + req.file.filename;
    }
    if (userInfo.password) {
        bcrypt.genSalt(10).then(salt => {
            bcrypt.hash(userInfo.password, salt).then(hashed => {
                userInfo.password = hashed;
                User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, userInfo, { new: true }).then(result => {
                    res.status(200).json(result);
                }).catch(err => {
                    res.status(400).send("Something went wrong");
                })
            })
        })
    } else {
        User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, userInfo, { new: true }).then(result => {
            res.status(200).json(result);
        }).catch(err => {
            res.status(400).send("Something went wrong");
        })
    }
})
```

as you can see the point where i find the user and send the query to update his info is duplicating code..how can i do this better?

Answer (score 0):

You could make your request handler `async` and then just use `await`

```
router.put("/editprofile", upload.single('image'), fileSizeLimitErrorHandler, verifyUser, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    ...

    if (userInfo.password) {
      let salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
      userInfo.password = await bcrypt.hash(userInfo.password, salt)
    }

    let result = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, userInfo, { new: true });
    res.status(200).json(result);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e) //or any other error handling you want
    res.status(400).send("Something went wrong");
  }
}
```